# Android: How to change the selected date's color in a DatePicker element?

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker

I am new to android programming and I want to use `DatePicker` element in my layout. I am able to use it successfully but I can't figure out how to change its selected date color. I have read many threads on this site and they talk about changing color in a `DatePickerDialog`. I have tried to follow similar approaches for the `DatePicker` element but could not do it. I can change the date's `textColor` using `calendarTextColor` attribute. My code for layout file is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <DatePicker
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/datePicker"
                android:datePickerMode="calendar"
                android:spinnersShown="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:layout_marginTop="-52dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
                style="@style/MyDatePickerStyleTheme"
                />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the corresponding styles.xml code:

```
<style name="MyDatePickerStyleTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent"> #00ff00 </item>

    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary"> #00ff00 </item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark"> #00ff00 </item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent"> #00ff00 </item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint"> #00ff00 </item>
    <!-- <item name="android:calendarTextColor"> #00ff00 </item> -->


</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerStyle">
    <item name="android:calendarTextColor"> #00ff00 </item>
</style>
```

Some extra points I like to add:

1. `android:calendarTextColor` attribute is working if I put it inside `MyDatePickerStyleTheme` but not working when putting inside `MydatePickerStyle`. 
    In other words the later theme style is not having any effect.
2. On different android versions (Lollipop and Marshmallow), same code gives very different looking layouts.
3. I just want to change selected date color for now, but how to change spacing between the dates and other styles in a good manner.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Add to your styles.xml

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/beautiful_color</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/beautiful_color</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
</style>
```

Then in the layout where is your view, add the **android:theme** attribute, instead of the *style*

```
<DatePicker
     android:theme="@style/MyDatePickerDialogTheme"
     android:id="@+id/datePicker"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
<!-- this is new -->
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

<item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primDark</item>
```

```
<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
<item name="android:headerBackground">@color/prim</item>
<item name="android:calendarTextColor">@color/primDark</item>
<item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">@color/primDark</item>
<item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@color/accent</item>
<item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
<item name="android:minDate">01/01/2000</item>
```

Comment: I tried what you have suggested but it was not working. And I had the colorAccent attribute before also.

Answer (score 0):

please go through the below link it working perfectly fine for me...
[change date picker theme color]

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Comment: I am not looking to use DatePickerDialog. And for the DatePicker, similar style is not working.